# how calculate icclim indicator tn10p over a period < 365 days of year

Tags: python, python-xarray, percentile

The goal is to calculate the climate indicator tn10p (percentage of days when Tmin < 10th percentile) based on the icclim package ([link](https://icclim.readthedocs.io/en/stable/references/ecad_functions_api.html#icclim._generated_api.tn10p)). Alternatively, I tried the same indicator from the xclim package. ([here](https://xclim.readthedocs.io/en/stable/indicators_api.html#xclim.indicators.atmos.tn10p)). I want to calculate the predicotor for a specific time period, e.g. '1960-12-01' to '1961-01-31', that can include two different years and is <= 12 months.

1 - open xarray dataset (for every 3 hours)

```
t2m = xa.open_dataset('filepath.nc', decode_cf = True, decode_coords = "all").sel(time=slice('1960-12-01', '1961-01-31'))
```

2 - calculate minimum daily temperature values

```
t2m_min = t2m.t2m.resample(time='1D').min(keep_attrs = True)
```

3.1 - With Icclim:

```
icclim_tn10p = icclim._generated_api.tn10p(in_files=t2m_min, slice_mode=['season',([12,1])])
```

3.2 - With xClim:

```
t2m_min_q10 = percentile_doy(arr = t2m_min, window=5, per=10).sel(percentiles=10)
xclim_tn10p = xclim.indicators.atmos.tn10p(tasmin = t2m_min, t10 = t2m_min_q10)
```

In both cases, 3.1 and 3.2, I get the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'dayofyear': length 61 on <this-array> and length 365 on {'longitude': 'longitude', 'latitude': 'latitude', 'dayofyear': 'dayofyear', 'percentiles': 'percentiles'}
```

I believe that the problem is the `percentile_doy` function ([link](https://xclim.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#xclim.core.calendar.percentile_doy)) that only seems to work witg 365 or 366 calendar days. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

It seems to be related to [this](https://github.com/Ouranosinc/xclim/issues/646) xclim issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following way works for icclim library:

- Compute tn10p for each year with slice_mode='month'
- Select the time range from the output array

However, the process decreases performance.